# Can't find a popup window opened via target="_blank"

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

I am working with a website that has a form that submits a POST request and opens the target page in a new window using `target="_blank"`. Firefox opens it in a new window.

When I do a loop like

```
String titles[];
do {
  titles = browser.getAllWindowTitles();
  System.out.println(titles.length);
} while (titles.length < 2);
```

It always prints out 1, even when the new window pops up and loads. How can I select this new window?
I am using `DefaultSelenium`. I have tried approaching it in other, indirect ways such as direct URL loading, but the site sends POST requests and I'm unable to simulate those.

Comment: Can you share the url if it is not confidential, so that we can debug the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately it is a secured website and the credentials are confidential. However after monitoring the traffic I found a way to pass URL tokens to load the desired page (seems like a flaw in the site's design), but am still not sure why selenium RC doesn't seem to detect this new window.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below alternative code and check if it is working as expected.

```
Set titles = browser.getAllWindowTitles(); 
Iterator i = titles.iterator(); 

while(i.hasNext()){
    System.out.println(titles.size);
}
```

Comment: It just says 1 repeatedly, even after the new window finishes loading up. I have read that there are cases where Selenium RC is unable to detect new windows.